# Is there a way to pass reactive key as value to v-model which is created by v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I got a bunch of inputs in my nuxt app and I'm trying to dynamically create them with v-for to shorten my code.
The problem is, v-model doesnt get the reactive object's key that i pass into the array that i used to create input elements with v-for, insted it gets binded to the array's related key.
I tried below example but it is not working:

```
<script setup>

const registerData = reactive({
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  ...  
});

const inputFields = [
  {
  id: 'name',
  type: 'text',
  vModel: registerData.name,
  },
  {
  id: 'surname',
  type: 'text',
  vModel: registerData.surname
  },
  ...
]

</script>
<template>

  <div v-for="input in inputFields">
    <input
     :id="input.id"
     :type="input.type"
     :v-model="input.vModel"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

This is not actually necessary but if it is doable, I would like to learn how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, kudos for putting repeated code into a for instead of copypasting!

At the moment, it is not working because the data you put into the `vModel` properties are not reactive - retrieving primitives from a Proxy (as created by reactive) are not reactive themselves.

Instead, you can put in the property name and resolve it with index access. So you would have to change the input definition like this:

```
{
  id: 'surname',
  type: 'text',
  vModelProp: 'surname' //<---  instead of registerData.surname
  },
```

And in the template:

```html
  <div v-for="input in inputFields">
    <input
     :id="input.id"
     :type="input.type"
     v-model="registerData[input.vModelProp]"
    />
  </div>
```

(note that there is no `:` in front of `v-model`)

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const {
  createApp,
  reactive
} = Vue;

const App = {
  setup() {

    const registerData = reactive({
      name: "le name",
      surname: "le surname",
    });

    const inputFields = [{
        id: 'name',
        type: 'text',
        vModelProp: 'name',
      },
      {
        id: 'surname',
        type: 'text',
        vModelProp: 'surname'
      },
    ]

    return {
      registerData,
      inputFields
    }
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="input in inputFields">
    {{input.id}}
      <input 
        :id="input.id" 
        :type="input.type" 
        v-model="registerData[input.vModelProp]" />
        {{input.vModelProp}}
  </div>
  registerData: {{ registerData }}
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to make `inputFields` reactive also:

```js
const { reactive } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const registerData = reactive({
      name: "",
      surname: "",
    });

    const inputFields = reactive([
      {id: 'name', type: 'text',vModel: registerData.name,},
      {id: 'surname', type: 'text', vModel: registerData.surname},
    ])
    return {
      inputFields, registerData
    };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="input in inputFields">
    <input
     :id="input.id"
     :type="input.type"
     v-model="input.vModel"
    />
  </div>
  {{ inputFields }}
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, interesting. That would replace the direct access to `registerData` in the declaration of the `vModel` property with the getter from the proxy, right? Noice, +1

Comment: I found Moritz's answer simpler but this is a great answer too, thanks.